# update multiple vertical bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to come up with some html and javascript to update multiple vertical bars. I've been able to get it to work for 1 bar with the following:

javascript

```
$('#inner').animate({height: + Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + "%"},500);
```

css

```
#outer {
width: 15px;
height: 140px;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#inner, #inner div {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
left: -2px;
position: absolute;
}

#inner {
border: 2px solid #000;
border-top-width: 0;
background-color: #090;

bottom: 0;
height: 0%;
}

#inner div {
border: 1px solid red;
border-bottom-width: 0;
background-color: orange;

top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
}
```

html

```
<div id="outer>
     <div id="inner">
     <div>height:'0%'</div>
     </div> 
</div>
```

what I want to do is have multiple bars updated with something like:

javascript

```
var number_of_bars=30;
for (var i=0; i<number_of_bars; i++) {
    $('#inner_'+ i).html('height:' + Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + "%");
}
```

but I need to have it reference specific individual divs. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you please add a jsfiddle?

Comment: using a class instead of id will do the trick I think

Comment: You want to update the bars upon click?

Comment: here is a fiddle of the base code http://jsfiddle.net/elwoodblues/TBDcq/

Comment: @Mysteryos, no, they will be updated by values feed in, but at this stage I'm just using Math.random to simulate the data

Comment: @sakhunzai, can you explain further?

Answer (score 1):

Here is working demo [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKSS5/2/)

The javascript is not optimal , I have just copied your code.

## js

```
function reload(){
    $('.inner').each(function(){
        $(this).animate({
        height: +Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "%"
        }, 500);
    });
};

setInterval(reload, 1000);
```

## html

```
<ul id="outer">
     <li style="height:100%;width:1px">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="inner">
        <div>height:'0%'</div>
    </li>
    <li class="inner">
        <div>height:'0%'</div>
    </li>
    <li class="inner">
        <div>height:'0%'</div>
    </li>
    <li class="inner">
        <div>height:'0%'</div>
    </li>
    <li class="inner">
        <div>height:'0%'</div>
    </li>
    <li class="inner">
        <div>height:'0%'</div>
    </li>
    <li class="inner">
        <div>height:'0%'</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## css

```
#outer {
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#outer li {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 99%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: inherit;
    width: 15px;
    background-color:green;
}

#outer li div{    
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Returns a random number between min and max
 */
function getRandomArbitary (min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Above Function copied from 
   [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

```
var number_of_bars=30;

var mini=100;
var maxi=$(window).height();

for (var i=0; i<number_of_bars; i++) {
    $('#inner_'+ i).html('height:' + getRandomArbitary (mini,maxi ) + "px");
}
```

I think **Height** should be in `px` not in `%` so that it can work

Comment: that doesn't address the issue of how to reference the css to it.